# How can I iterate a Petgraph node's edges with the nodes they connect?

Tags: rust, petgraph

The [`edges` function of a Petgraph Graph](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html#method.edges) returns an iterator of edges. Each iteration then returns an [`EdgeReference`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/src/petgraph/graph_impl/mod.rs.html#2011-2015) which handily stores both nodes and the edge weight, which you can see if you debug print one. But unfortunately the `EdgeReference` members are all private, so you can't access them in your code.

So how can I iterate both the edges and nodes connected to a node? This seems like something that should be simple, but I haven't been able to find any example code out there.

Comment: Is `source` and `target` what you need? https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/visit/trait.EdgeRef.html#tymethod.source

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes they are, thank you! Do you want to write up a quick answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`edges` returns a iterator for [`EdgeReference`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/graph/struct.EdgeReference.html) which implements the [`EdgeRef`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.5.1/petgraph/visit/trait.EdgeRef.html) trait which has a `source` and `target` that return `NodeIndex` which can be used to get the node from the graph.

Comment: I think that things have changed with 0.6 :(  I get "error[E0599]: no method named `target` found for struct `petgraph::graph::EdgeReference` in the current scope`." there also is no such field.